# No action was found on the controller that matches the request angularjs GET

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Can somebody please help me what am I missing or doing wrong. I am getting following error :

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:52096/api/Wotc/GetWotcDashBoardSummary?0=9&1=4&2=-&3=3&4=3&5=8&6=5&7=6&8=6&9=6'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'WotcAPI' that matches the request."}
```

wotcDashBoard.js :

```
var WotcDashBoardModule = angular.module('WotcDashBoardModule', []);

WotcDashBoardModule.factory('WotcDashBoardModuleService', ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {

    return {
        GetDashBoardSummary: function (Ein) {
            return $http({
                url: '/api/Wotc/GetWotcDashBoardSummary',
                method: 'GET',
                params: Ein
            });
        }       
    };
}]);


WotcDashBoardModule.controller('WotcDashBoardController', ['$scope', 'WotcDashBoardModuleService', function ($scope, WotcDashBoardModuleService) {

    var Ein = '00-00000';
    WotcDashBoardModuleService.GetDashBoardSummary(Ein).then(function (response) {
         $scope.Summary = response.data.Employees;
    });

}]);
```

WotcAPIController :

```
  [RoutePrefix("api/Wotc")]
    public class WotcAPIController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetWotcDashBoardSummary")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetWotcDashBoardSummary(string Id)
        {
            CompanyWotcBO wotcSummary = new CompanyWotcBO();

            try
            {wotcSummary = await CompanyWotcBL.GetDashBoardSummary(Id);}
            catch
            {}
            return Ok(new { WotcSummary = wotcSummary });
        }
    }
```

Route.config :

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Jobs",
                url: "Jobs/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Jobs", action = "ShowJobPosting", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "HomeInit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what is this query string `0=9&1=4&2=-&3=3&4=3&5=8&6=5&7=6&8=6&9=6`? It is not consistent with the code you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is a **parameter name mismatch**.

Changed `params: Ein` to `params: { id: ein }`  in wotcDashBoard.js.

code :

```
return {
        GetDashBoardSummary: function (Ein) {
            return $http({
                url: '/api/Wotc/GetWotcDashBoardSummary',
                method: 'GET',
                params: { id: ein }
            });
        }       
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which I think need's fix:

Firstly: instead of `url: '/api/Wotc/GetWotcDashBoardSummary',`it should be something like `url: 'http://www.example.com/api/Wotc/GetWotcDashBoardSummary/id',` where example.com is the domain where you have hosted your service.

Secondly:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Wotc")]
public class WotcAPIController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetWotcDashBoardSummary/{id}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetWotcDashBoardSummary(string Id)
    {
        CompanyWotcBO wotcSummary = new CompanyWotcBO();

        try
        {wotcSummary = await CompanyWotcBL.GetDashBoardSummary(Id);}
        catch
        {}
        return Ok(new { WotcSummary = wotcSummary });
    }
}
```

You might have to enable  [CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors) after doing this if you get any Cross-origin-request errors.